# How can I pass json data returned from a webservice into D3.json(...)?

Tags: jquery, json, xml, d3.js, nvd3.js

Thank you for your help so far! I was able to successfully build my webservice and NVD3.js stacked area chart. However, I have been struggling without any success in passing json data from my webservice into my NVD3.js graph. On my webform, I select two dates for an interval and click a "go" button.

I feel that it is something obvious that I am missing. If not possible, is there a way of saving the json data returned from my webservice into a regular file (e.g. myFile.json), so that I can pass it in my graph? Thank you very much for your help! Here is my latest attempt:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#btGO").click(function(){
                var startDate = $("#startDate").val();
                var endDate = $("#endDate").val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: "dataWebService.asmx/getCasesForDateInterval",
                    method: "post",
                    data: {
                        startDate: startDate,
                        endDate: endDate
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        //This is where I attempt to pass my json data
                        d3.json(data, function (error, data) {
                            nv.addGraph(function () {
                                var chart = nv.models.stackedAreaChart()
                                              .x(function (d) { return d[0] })
                                              .y(function (d) { return d[1] })
                                              .clipEdge(true)
                                              .useInteractiveGuideline(true);

                                chart._options.controlOptions = ['Expanded', 'Stacked'];

                                chart.xAxis
                                    .showMaxMin(true)
                                    .tickFormat(function (d) { return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d)) });

                                chart.yAxis
                                    .tickFormat(d3.format(',.0f'));

                                d3.select('#chart svg')
                                  .datum(data)
                                    .transition().duration(500).call(chart);

                                nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

                                return chart;
                            });
                        });
                    }
                });

            });
        });
     </script>
```

Here is my webservice:

```
    [WebMethod]
     public string getTotalForDateInterval(string startDate, string endDate)
    {
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["vetDatabase_Wizard"].ConnectionString;
    List<keyValues> master = new List<keyValues>();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_CountAndGroupByDate", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        //Linking SQL parameters with webmethod parameters
        SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@startDate",
            Value = startDate
        };

        SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@endDate",
            Value = endDate
        };

        cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);
        con.Open();

        //Get time in milliseconds
        DateTime start = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        DateTime end = DateTime.ParseExact(endDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        DateTime utime = DateTime.ParseExact("1970-01-01", "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        long startMilliseconds = (long)((start - utime).TotalMilliseconds);
        long endMilliseconds = (long)((end - utime).TotalMilliseconds);
        const long oneDayInMilliseconds = 86400000;

        //Declare temp dictionary to store the lists
        Dictionary<string, List<long[]>> temp = new Dictionary<string, List<long[]>>();
        string[] buildings = { "SSB", "GEN", "LYM", "LUD", "GCC", "MAC", "MMB" };

        //Create building lists and initialize them with individual days and the default value of 0 
        foreach (string building in buildings){
            temp.Add(building, new List<long[]>());
            for (long j = startMilliseconds; j <= endMilliseconds; j = j + oneDayInMilliseconds){
                long[] timeTotal = { j, 0 };
                temp[building].Add(timeTotal);
            }
        }

        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {

            //Remove time from dateTime2 and assign totals for appropriate date
            string s = (rdr["dateOpened"].ToString()).Substring(0, 10);
            DateTime dateOpened = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            long time = (long)((dateOpened - utime).TotalMilliseconds);
            long total = (long)Convert.ToInt32(rdr["total"]);

            string buildingName = rdr["building"].ToString();
            int index = temp[buildingName].FindIndex(r => r[0].Equals(time));
            temp[buildingName][index][1] = total;
        }
            //add all the keyValue objects to master list
            for (int i = 0; i < buildings.Length; i++)
            {
                keyValues kv = new keyValues();
                kv.key = buildings[i];
                kv.values = temp[kv.key];
                master.Add(kv);
            }

      }
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    //Serialize list object into a JSON array and write in into the response stream
    string ss = js.Serialize(master);
    return ss;

}
```

Here is the structure of the json returned from my webservice. I get the file within script tags:

[image]

Comment: A word of advice: you are opening A LOT of duplicate questions on this subject.  In some of them people have supplied comments and answers that you have not responded to.  This is very much against stack overflow etiquette and will make users unwilling to help you.  For instance the answer I give below [duplicates an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37759986/16363) @cyril gave you over a month ago.

Comment: @Mark Hi Mark! Thank you for your answer. I agree with you: I did post very similar/duplicate questions while not answering back, and it does look bad. The solutions didn't work because of some unrelated bugs that I have just picked up by using Google's inspector. Still, I should have answered them back. I get so focused sometimes that it becomes disrespectful towards others. I apologize for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call both `$.ajax` and `d3.json`, these methods do the same thing and I would just use:

```
 d3.json("dataWebService.asmx/getCasesForDateInterval", function (error, data) {
```

Second, if you stick with the `$.ajax` call your method is actually a `GET` not a `POST` since you can navigate to it in a web-browser.

Third, and your biggest problem, your web service is not returning JSON.  It's returning a JSON string wrapped in XML (this is the default for **older** Microsoft SOAP based web services).  You should be able to force JSON by adding this attribute to top of your methods:

```
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string getTotalForDateInterval(string startDate, string endDate)
```